# ORA-06413: Connection not open, works fine in Visual Studio C# but gives error in Installer

Tags: c#, oracle, installation, database-connection

I have developed an application that uses Oracle Database to insert/query.
Application works fine when I run using Visual Studio, but when I create its MSI Setup using Visual Studio Installer or Inno Setup Creation, it doesn't connect to Database and gives error on OracleConnection.Open().

Here is its full exception message

> System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-06413:
>   Connection not open.
>
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException.Check(OciErrorHandle
>   errorHandle, Int32 rc)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String
>   userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
>   at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString
>   connectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) 
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()    at
>   XML_Reader.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   D:\XML_Reader_11NOV2015\XML_Reader\XML_Reader\Program.cs:line 33

Comment: you may try Properties -> Build -> Target Platform to x86 or AnyCPU

Comment: Its alreay as you suggested.
Any other idea ?

Comment: And also please check connection string twice.

Comment: Connection string is constant, either in Visual Studio or Setup.

Comment: There is an obscure error in older Oracle versions to do with brackets in the files names.  So you could check this:  https://community.oracle.com/message/11103466.  Otherwise, make sure that your TNSnames.ora is correctly set-up on the machine you are running from, and that you can connect from this machine using sqlplus or similar.

Comment: I am using both Visual Studio and Installer on my same PC.
Its gets successfully connected thru Visual Studio debug mode but gives same error when I execute Exe from installer.
Here is my connection string
Connection String is : Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.11.12.6)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=FCUBSAWS)));User ID=GOLD;Password=GOLD;Unicode=True